# How to set tableview cell separator to 100% width in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ipad, swift3

I'm developing my first app, and have got everything working except I have discovered a display issue on iPad, where the separator of a cell is limited in width (see screenshot)

**Screen shot on iPad**

[image: Screen Shot]

I've tried everything that I can find on how to set the margins to 0, etc,
including:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! MyCell

    myCell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    myCell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    myCell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    return myCell
}
```

I'm not using storyboard and I am doing it programmatically,

Any ideas would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's caused by `Readable Content Guide`. You can disable it by setting `tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false`

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad that I can help you :D Could you please accept my answer?

Comment: It is false by default, so this answer doesn't help

Comment: @amitooshacham Since then, Apple added a new API about the separator margin in iOS 10 or 11 (I'm not sure about the iOS version). So you may need to have a look at that API too