# Swift - Adjust size on separator of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, separator

I have at problem with my cells in a UITableView. I have used the Attribute Inspector to adjust the size. Like this:

[image]

But the adjustment only applied on the cells with content. How do I make the separator to be the same size for the whole tableview using Swift or the Attribute Inspector?

[image]

Comment: Do you need to show cells without content?

Comment: You can add fake cells with your desired separator.

Comment: Another point of view, is even required to display separators for no cells? why not to let it be a blank space with separators after displaying all cells?

Comment: so you dont want space at the end of separator, right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075508/how-to-set-tableview-cell-separator-to-100-width-in-swift-3-0

Answer (score 0):

For your question, you can try this

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Another way you can do like this.

Then,

**In cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
let horizontalGap = 15.0 as CGFloat
// As you want to have equal gaping in left & right side, you have to position the view's origin.x to the constant and have to have the width minus the double of that constant.
let seperatorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: horizontalGap, y: cell.frame.size.height - 1, width: cell.frame.size.width - horizontalGap * 2.0, height: 1))
seperatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
cell.addSubview(seperatorView)
```

---

**In Storyboard**

Change `Separator` as `None` in `Attributes Inspector`. Drag `UIView` and place it inside your `cell` . Give constraints like, `Leading 15, Trailing 15, Bottom 0 and height 1`. Change background color to `red`